# Figures of speech like “Adam’s Ale”

Tags: idioms, terminology

Is there a name for the type of figure of speech exemplified by the following?

*Adam’s ale*

*Shanks’s pony*

*Glasgow kiss*

*Croydon face-lift*

*country mile*

The common feature being a noun phrase of the form *modifier noun* which ostensibly refer to a type of *noun* but in fact refer ironically to something quite different. E.g. *Adam’s ale* means water, *Shanks’s pony* means travelling on foot etc. These are also usually slang phrases.

Comment: Would *Idiom* work?

Comment: @k1eran *idiom* is too broad a term. I’m looking for a term that refers specifically to idioms of the given form. Quite possibly there isn’t one.

Comment: Strong collocation ... compound.

Comment: I guess they would be ironic idioms.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a common term for them. If I had to come up with something, I'd say *ironic idiom*. They're idioms because the meaning of the phrases are different from the literal meanings of the words. And they're ironic because those meanings are actually somewhat contradictory to the literal meanings.